# Repeatedly call function with postDelayed() for n times

Tags: android, kotlin, delay, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I'm currently working on a timer functionality which makes use of `handler.postDelayed()`

I want to call the same function once it completes for `n` times.

i.e I want to repeat a delayed function for n times.

**Example code of the function:**

```
fun delayProgress(...){
        
        handler.postDelayed({
            ......
        }, 1000)

        handler.postDelayed({
            ....
        }, 2000)
        handler.postDelayed({
            ...
        }, 3000)
       
    }
```

**Things I tried:**

Kotlin coroutine

> runBlocking with repeat()

> delay()

**Edit 1:**

```
runBlocking {  
            launch {
                repeat(3) {
                    delayProgress(...)
                    delay(3000)
                }
            }
        }
```

The above code didn't run as expected the `delay()` blocks UI for 3 seconds and when released the function `delayProgress()` skips 3 seconds and executes 3 times parallelly and not sequentially.

Comment: So you want to call `delayProgress` n times?

Comment: `yourScope.launch { repeat(n) { yourFunction(); delay(1000) } }` must work. You say you "tried" it, maybe you should post the code you used to try it.

Comment: I'ts not `delay()` that blocks the UI, but `runBlocking` -- just as its name says. You need to remove it and use a proper scope object (one tied to the lifecycle of the UI component you're doing this in). To try it out you can use `GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main)` as a temporary approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `postDelayed` you can just do

```
val n = 3
repeat(n) { i -> handler.postDelayed({ ... }, (i+1) * 1000 }
```

With your coroutine example, you're using `runBlocking` so the coroutine you launch will block the thread. What your code is doing is calling `delayProgress` (which posts a bunch of runnables to the message queue) and then blocking for three seconds.

Once that delay ends, three seconds have passed and all your runnables are (over)due, so they all get processed at once.

I'm not really sure what you're doing though - posting runnables to the handler is one way to defer work, coroutines are another. You're combining both to perform a task 9 times. What's your use case here?

A typical way to do this with runnables is to have the runnable repost itself (or create a new runnable) with a delay when it executes, and have it check whether it should do that (e.g. give it a counter it can decrement, so it only fires three times, or set a started/stopped flag)